# How to add multiple classes to a condition in angular

Tags: angular

I have this code

```
    <div *ngFor="let d of getDays(); let i = index" class="day hr left" (click)="pick(d, h)" [class.white]="days[d].indexOf(h) > -1">
</div>
```

It works fine but my question is how do I add another class name in this part `[class.white]="days[d].indexOf(h) > -1"`? I have another class called `.redborder{border 1px solid red}`. I tried this but didn't work `[class.white.redborder]="days[d].indexOf(h) > -1"`. What else am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) directive:

```
<element [ngClass]="{'white redborder' : days[d].indexOf(h) > -1}"></element>
```

For `elseif` I guess you can use this:

```
<element [ngClass]="days[d].indexOf(h) > -1 ? 'white' : 'redborder'"></element>
```

Comment: Wow thnx man, it worked @PierreDuc. How about multiple conditions as in the case of else if?

Comment: @SamZiggler I've updated my  answer to show else if. It is however advised to use as little logic inside your templates, and use functions or getters in your component class. This helps refactoring and testing, and increases readability